# Importing GPG Key

Tags: import, gpg, keys

I have problems importing my GPG-Keys into my new installation of debian. I exportet the private-key a few years ago. Now I am trying to get everything running under a new debian.

I tried to do

```
  gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import private-key.asc
```

But I only get this:

```
gpg: Keine gültigen OpenPGP-Daten gefunden.
gpg: Anzahl insgesamt bearbeiteter Schlüssel: 0
```

which translates to:

```
gpg: No valid OpenPGP-Data found
gpg: Number of processed Keys : 0
```

The file looks correct and starts with

```
--BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.9 (GNU/Linux)
```

and ends with

```
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer. There were some --- missing at the beginng.

Comment: It was driving me crazy until I found this answer and I realized the issue: I was piping the wrong command, making gpg to receive an error as stdout. Thank you so much.